# Simple PHP Dom find parent wrapper if element contains ‘xyz’

Tags: php, domparser

apologies if already covered elsewhere... I’m successfully using Simple PHP Dom in one way but trying to expand a little.

Situation:
Creating a site for the Yallourn/Yallourn North football club.

I get my score data from here: http://websites.sportstg.com/comp_info.cgi?client=1-6177-0-434611-0&pool=1&action=ROUND&round=0

Basically I am struggling to get simple php Dom to scan the above page, where it finds “Yallourn/Yallourn North”, have it echo grab the details of the two teams (in this case Yallourn/Yallourn North and Thorpdale).

Basically always trying to find the elements relevant to Yallourn/Yallourn North.

Any points would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see that they are using AngularJS and probably the table is generated dynamically which means that you will not succeed to parse the page via PHP, because there is data that is rendered on the client side. I suggest you to try find some other data source

Comment: The actual data is inlined in the page, near the bottom as a javascript object. Try parsing out the line starting with `<script>var matches = [{"PoolIDHome":"1"` (that's line 1079 in the current HTML), and see if you can parse that into a data structure.